# making gridcontrol right to left, but caption of column is disappears 

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, devexpress

Because of devexpress  doesn't support Arabic for grid control I am trying to do mirroring for grid control, I do it successfuly but the problem is when I am Hover the cursor of mouse on column header the caption of column  is disappears !!!! 
I dont know why ?? and I want to solve this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem the workaround is:

Make your own control inherits from `xtragrid` and also override the
the `mousemove` event and `mousehover` event add the line `this.Invalidate();`